# How filter a date with Lexik Form Filter bundle in symfony2?

Tags: forms, symfony, filter

I'm trying to filter a list of articles by publish date using Lexik Form Filter bundle.

My entity:

```
class Article {
    [...]

    /**
      * @ORM\Column(name="publish_date", type="datetime", nullable=true)
      */
    protected $publishDate;

    [...]
}
```

My form type:

```
class ArticleFilterType extends AbstractType{

    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('publishDate', 'filter_date');
        [...]
    }

    public function getName()
{
    return 'article_filter';
}


public function setDefaultOptions(OptionsResolverInterface $resolver)
{
    $resolver->setDefaults(array(
        'data_class'        => 'Orm\CrawlerBundle\Entity\Article',
        'csrf_protection'   => false,
        'validation_groups' => array('filter'),
    ));

}
```

When I filter filling the form with a publish date of one of my articles I've no result. What is the problem? The type I'm using for the date in db is datetime.

Thanks!

Comment: What do you enter in the form ?

Comment: The publish date field of my form is rendered as three text boxes (month, day, and year). I enter the date of one of my articles, for example, Dec-3-2014. Instead, in the db I've the publish date value "2014-12-03 01:00:00" for the article.

Comment: I choose the date from the 3 select inputs

Answer (score 1):

I guess you should use the filter_datetime or filter_datetime_range from Lexik :

```
public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder->add('publishDate', 'filter_datetime');
        [...]
    }
```

Comment: I want filter my articles only by date. Also if I used filter_datetime with exactly the value on db I've no result. I think there is a problem with the date format but I don't Know what I've to do.

Comment: can you post the content of your controller and what is in the logs of the debugger

Answer (score 0):

Controller:

```
class ArticleController extends Controller {

/**
 * Lists all Article entities.
 *
 * @Route("/article_admin", name="article_admin")
 * @Template()
 */
public function listArticleAction() {
    /** @var ArticleBiz $em */
    $em = $this->get('orm_crawler.articlebiz');
    $form = $this->createForm(new ArticleFilterType());

    // initialize a query builder
    /** @var QueryBuilder $filterBuilder */
    $filterBuilder = $em->getRepository()->createQueryBuilder('e');
    if ($this->get('request')->query->has($form->getName())) {
        // manually bind values from the request
        $form->submit($this->get('request')->query->get($form->getName()));
        // build the query from the given form object
        $this->get('lexik_form_filter.query_builder_updater')->addFilterConditions($form, $filterBuilder);
    }

    $paginator = $this->get('knp_paginator')->paginate($filterBuilder->getQuery(), $this->getRequest()->query->get('page', 1), 10);

    return array(
        'form' => $form->createView(),
        'paginator' => $paginator
    );
}
```